# そ and も meaning in その中でも

Tags: meaning

I need some help in understanding the meaning of そ and も in その中でも. I understand that の中で by itself carries the meaning of among but I could not figure out the contribution of the two other hiraganas the phrase.
Additionally, why do の中で means among? Anyone know the etymology of the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're parsing it wrong: [その](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%85%B6%E3%81%AE) is a single word, so 「その中でも」means something like "Also inside/among that" (with [も](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%82) meaning "also, too").

As for 「の中で」, [「中」](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%AD) also means "among", so 「Xの中」 means "Inside X", "Among X" (like 「Xの右」 means "To the right of X").